# Best way to make an APP in mode landscape and portrait

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, landscape-portrait

what is the best way to make an APP that works in landscape and portrait?

I have tried to try with autosizing but doesn't work well because i want to use all the width of the screen. Should i use two views? I have done the UIViewController using the Storyboard.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to easily support both orientations is to use UITableViews and the standard UITableViewCell Styles.

Once you need a custom UITableViewCell you will have to configure the auto-layout constraints yourself. They are a great time saver once you get used to them.

Check out the

[WWDC 2012 Introduction to Auto-Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/)

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a little more specific with your question? I'm not quite sure I understand what you are asking.

If you mean to ask how you can set the app to default to Landscape orientation, then just go to the main project, under "Targets" it should have your app name, and then you can see the options for "Supported Interface Orientations"

Answer (score 0):

Using two views is easy at first but when you need to make adjustments, it becomes extremely difficult. One modification to one view needs to be modified on another view. Using auto-layout is the best way I believe. Yes it's extremely difficult to get a handle of it at first but once you get to used to auto-layout, it becomes such a breeze to make modifications.